# Quasi-algebraically closed fields reference request

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am looking for a roadmap to understanding what [quasi-algebraically closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-algebraically_closed_field#Ck_fields) are with the ultimate goal of understanding the paper by [Lang 1952](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969785).

My current background is the first 6 chapters from Milne's notes [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf). Currently I am also studying the 7th chapter from the same notes and the chapter on Brauer groups from [Milne's notes on class field theory](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf).

I am also familiar with Russian besides English. Apologizes if the question is not placed in an appropriate place, but I really seek some help here.

**EDIT**: When I originally posted this question on  overflow (and was suggested to move it here), I was advised a resource called *Forms of Higher Degree* by M.J. Greenberg. However, upon a google search I was not able to find such a title.

Comment: I think the right title might be "Lectures on forms in many variables"